# scipy.optimize.minimize('Newton-CG') doesn't always return lowest objective function it finds

Tags: python, scipy

Strange behavior in the Newton-CG minimization function with scipy: every time I make a call to the objective function calculation, I print out the value. I find that often, the minimizer finds a lower value than it ends up reporting in the end. Example output is shown below. "Iter" is the iteration number from the minimize function, while "call" is which time the minimizer called a calculation of the objective function "J". "dJ" is how much J changed from the previous call. "f" is an object class that contains all the calculations, including the callback function 'iternum':

```
res=scipy.optimize.minimize(f.J,f.z,args=(F),tol=1.e-4,method='Newton-CG', \
 jac=f.Jacobian,hessp=f.Hessian, callback=f.iternum)

Iter 1    , call 30    J=3.73e+09 dJ=3.58e+09  
Iter 1    , call 31    J=1.78e+09 dJ=-1.95e+09 
Iter 1    , call 32    J=5.23e+08 dJ=-1.26e+09 
Iter 1    , call 33    J=1.76e+08 dJ=-3.47e+08 
Iter 1    , call 34    J=1.33e+08 dJ=-4.29e+07 
Iter 1    , call 35    J=1.44e+08 dJ=1.14e+07  
Iter 2    , call 36    J=1.42e+08 dJ=-1.85e+06 
Iter 2    , call 37    J=1.42e+08 dJ=5.19e+04  

res.fun = 1.42e+08
```

However, note that the lowest J value is actually 1.33e+08, so those parameters and that objective function value should have been returned. Anyone else experience this? Ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to put that in. I expected it to accept the fit with J=1.33e+08 and return those parameters instead. I edited the post to say this.

Comment: I have seen this mostly in situations where the solution did not satisfy bounds/constraints, or when the function was called to estimate the gradient. Neither seems to apply in your case, though.

Comment: For now I just have a simple if-then statement to always save the parameters for the best value of the objective function, which I return myself at the end. Still, pretty annoying; wondering if I should consider it a bug and run it up the flagpole with the scipy folks.

Comment: Does it matter that much? Maybe running one more iteration would give you a much lower cost function than tracking previous values... As for filing a bug, I would wait a few days. Some of the scipy folks are active here and may have some more athoritative input than me :)

Comment: This is very broad. There is no code to run, we can't see your callback, the solver-status is not shown, and most importantly: quite badly scaled objective with a not that small tolerance.